# Build C files in my RubyGem

Tags: ruby, rake, rubygems, rakefile

I'm trying to package my ruby application as a RubyGem (using Jeweler and Rake). I've some C source which I need to build on the target machine where the gem is to be installed and then place the output in the gem's bin directory so that my ruby code can use it.

Is there any hook by which I can execute commands during gem installation?

A snippet from my Rakefile looks like this:

```
task :install do
  puts "Install"
  `touch /tmp/install`
end

task :build do
  puts "Build"
  `touch /tmp/build`
end
```

When I execute `rake build` it outputs `Build` and when I execute `rake install` the output is `Build` followed by `Install`. The problem comes when I do `gem install` then the `install` task is not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need gemspec extensions:

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#extensions

Basically you can run any ruby code you like when the gem is installed.

Comment: Great! But it looks like it needs an `extconf.rb` file and which should result in a `Makefile` in that directory.